# Keras : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim' when using model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

## when triying to fit the model  i get this error

i'm using Keras and every time i try to fit my model

```
padded_model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, verbose=1)
```

i get this error :

> 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: What is `train_x` and `train_y`? They need to be numpy arrays or list of numpy arrays.

Comment: @umutto i've got train_c and train y using train_test_split : 'train_X, test_X, train_y, 'test_y = train_test_split(padded_docs, y, 
                                                    train_size=0.7,
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=123)'

Comment: Please include the types of train_X and train_y using the type() function in python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `train_x` and `train_y` are normal Python lists, they don't have the attribute `.ndim`. Only Numpy arrays have this attribute representing the number of dimensions.

(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html)

Comment: So the Problem is that the function fit cannot treate lists ?

Comment: Basically yes, but it is also not recommended to use lists. Numpy is a special package to speed up numerical calculations. Using pure Python lists is much slower and not recommended for this purpose. But it is easy to turn a list into a Numpy array if the module is installed. Just pass the list to the array constructor: `x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])`